# Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-membership

When I attempt to create the stored procedure below I get the following error:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

It's not clear to me what is causing this error. UserID is in fact an int in all of my tables. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
create procedure dbo.DeleteUser(@UserID int)
as

    delete from [aspnet_Membership] where UserId = @UserID
    delete from [Subscription] where UserID = @UserID
    delete from [Address] where UserID = @UserID
    delete from [User] where UserID = @UserID

go
```

Comment: Pretty sure `aspnet_Membership` does use `guids`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sounds to me like at least one of those tables has defined `UserID` as a `uniqueidentifier`, not an `int`. Did you check the data in each table? What does `SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM` each table yield? An `int` or a `GUID`?

**EDIT**

I think you have built a procedure based on all tables that contain a column named UserID. I think you should not have included the `aspnet_Membership` table in your script, since it's not really one of "your" tables.

If you meant to design your tables around the `aspnet_Membership` database, then why are the rest of the columns `int` when that table clearly uses a `uniqueidentifier` for the `UserID` column?

Comment: Ah yes...that was it.  The membership table has it stored as a guid.  Embarrassing.

Comment: If you're going to be mixing your own definition of UserID with the membership provider, perhaps it might make sense to name your identifier something other than UserID.

Comment: Indeed.  Poor design decision on my part.

Answer (score 4):

If you're accessing this via a View then [try `sp_recompile` or refreshing views.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx)

`sp_recompile`:

Causes stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions to be recompiled the next time that they are run. It does this by dropping the existing plan from the procedure cache forcing a new plan to be created the next time that the procedure or trigger is run. In a SQL Server Profiler collection, the event SP:CacheInsert is logged instead of the event SP:Recompile.

**Arguments**

```
[ @objname= ] 'object'
```

The qualified or unqualified name of a stored procedure, trigger, table, view, or user-defined function in the current database. object is nvarchar(776), with no default. If object is the name of a stored procedure, trigger, or user-defined function, the stored procedure, trigger, or function will be recompiled the next time that it is run. If object is the name of a table or view, all the stored procedures, triggers, or user-defined functions that reference the table or view will be recompiled the next time that they are run.

**Return Code Values**

0 (success) or a nonzero number (failure)

**Remarks**

`sp_recompile` looks for an object in the current database only.

The queries used by stored procedures, or triggers, and user-defined functions are optimized only when they are compiled. As indexes or other changes that affect statistics are made to the database, compiled stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions may lose efficiency. By recompiling stored procedures and triggers that act on a table, you can reoptimize the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the data doesn't match the datatype.
I have come across the same issues that I forgot to make the fields match. Though my case is not same as yours, but it shows the similar error message.

The situation is that I copy a table, but accidently I misspell one field, so I change it using the `ALTER` after creating the database. And the order of fields in both table is not identical. so when I use the `INSERT INTO TableName SELECT * FROM TableName`, the result showed the similar errors: `Operand type clash: datetime is incompatible with uniqueidentifier`

This is a simiple example:

```sql
use example
go
create table Test1 (
    id int primary key,
    item uniqueidentifier,
    inserted_at datetime
    )
go
create table Test2 (
    id int primary key,
    inserted_at datetime
    )
go
alter table Test2 add item uniqueidentifier;
go

--insert into Test1 (id, item, inserted_at) values (1, newid(), getdate()), (2, newid(), getdate());


insert into Test2 select * from Test1;

select * from Test1;
select * from Test2;
```

The error message is:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 24
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime
```